# Categorizing information from html tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There could be a better title for my question but here it is:
I return elements from html to a list by using BeautifulSoup with findall and here is a sample of what I get:

```
[<div class="tightLt col span-1-3">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="cell"><i class="sqLed middle sm yellow margRtXs "></i></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="middle">Neutral Outlook</span></div>
    </div>
</div>,
<div class="tightLt col span-1-3">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="cell"><i class="sqLed middle sm yellow margRtXs "></i></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="middle"><span class="showDesk">No opinion of</span> CEO</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>]
[<div class="tightLt col span-1-3">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="cell"><i class="sqLed middle sm red margRtXs "></i></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="middle">Doesn't Recommend</span></div>
    </div>
</div>,
<div class="tightLt col span-1-3">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="cell"><i class="sqLed middle sm red margRtXs "></i></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="middle">Negative Outlook</span></div>
    </div>
</div>,
<div class="tightLt col span-1-3">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="cell"><i class="sqLed middle sm yellow margRtXs "></i></div>
        <div class="cell"><span class="middle"><span class="showDesk">No opinion of</span> CEO</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>]
```

The problem is that in the first html, CEO approval (in these two cases corresponding value for CEO approval is "No opinion of CEO" but it could be also "Disapproval of CEO" and "Approval of CEO") is the second element in the list inside the `"span"` tag, but it is the third one in the second html. So I can not select the elements from the lists by using list indices. How could I solve my problem?

Here is the part of the code that returns above list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Walmart-Reviews-E715.htm"
html_content = response = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(html_content, "lxml")
        reviews = soup.find("div", id="EmployerReviews").find_all("li", class_="empReview")
        for review in reviews:
           x = soup.findAll("div", class_="cell reviewBodyCell") 
           for z in x:
               z.findAll("div", class_="tightLt col span-1-3")#returns the list that contains needed information
```

Comment: You are referring to 'CEO approval' which doesn't appear in the provided HTML. Should we assume that you are referring to the second column. It would be helpful if your question would include exactly what you are trying to get out. Some code to get started would also be useful.

Comment: post your current code, html markup is not enough

Comment: sorry about this, I meant " >No opinion of</span> CEO" corresponds to Ceo approval both in first and second html lists

Comment: ok I will post the full code but you will need to log in first to get the data

Comment: It `for x in soup.select("[class='showDesk']"):print(x.text)` should give you the same result you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended and optimized solution with *BeautifulSoup* [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Walmart-Reviews-E715.htm"
html_content = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

selector = "div#EmployerReviews li.empReview div.cell.reviewBodyCell span[class='showDesk']"
for x in soup.select(selector):
    print(x.parent.text)
```

The output:

```
No opinion of CEO
No opinion of CEO
No opinion of CEO
No opinion of CEO
Approves of CEO
No opinion of CEO
Approves of CEO
Approves of CEO
Approves of CEO
```

Comment: How did you determine the selector?

Comment: @edyvedy13, experience, my friend ... experience )

Comment: Could you please explain me how :) ? because I have to deal with the same thing at different points

Comment: Because when I just right click and say copy selector I don't get the same

Comment: @edyvedy13, `div#EmployerReviews li.empReview div.cell.reviewBodyCell span[class='showDesk']` is the complete path hierarchy to the needed span elements containing CEO marks. That's all

Comment: But how did you track it? Sorry if my question is very trivial

Comment: @edyvedy13, it's simple logic : your current code contains nested `for` loops with `find_all` pointing to elements hierarchy. I have also analyzed the markup visually

Comment: If I wanted to do the same other two elements, I could not do the same right? because they both have <span class="middle"

Comment: @edyvedy13, it would depend where they are located in the hierarchy. I.e. : we are analyzing the markup visually beforehand to define the parents/siblings of the crucial nodes